# Regex non capturing group is returning results while the capturing group is not in python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to retrieve data from a json element within a HTML page with python 3.

My regex looks like this:

```
re.findall(r'(?:(dataLayerLocal\.products = ))\[.*\];', response.body.decode("utf-8"))
```

For a snipped starting like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    dataLayerLocal.products = dataLayerLocal.products || [];
    dataLayerLocal.products = [{'amount':'0','categories':['
```

Unfortunatelly the non capturing group is capturing, and the part I want is not included:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(?:(dataLayerLocal\.products = ))\[.*\];', response.body.decode("utf-8"))
['dataLayerLocal.products = ']
```

This one works, but returns me the unwanted part:

```
>>> re.findall("dataLayerLocal\.products = \[.*\];", response.body.decode("utf-8"))
["dataLayerLocal.products = [{'amount':'0','cate
```

Full demo:

https://regex101.com/r/Qpds6V/1

How can I get a result starting like this?

```
[{'amount':'0'
```

Comment: Capture what you need: `re.findall(r'dataLayerLocal\.products = (\[.*\]);', text)`, see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qpds6V/3) and the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/0BvO8f)

Comment: Thank you, that worked.